# Syntax issue with match method

Tags: ruby, regex, nokogiri, match

I want to match whatever word is after `">`. This is my example text, and text to match.

```
<a href="http://www.foo.bar">example_text (a)</a>
```

Text to grab:

```
example_text
```

Here's my code:

```
$page_html = Nokogiri::HTML.parse($browser.html)
$holder = $page_html.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/a')
$user = $holder.match('(?<=\"\>)\w*')
```

And my error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
$user = $holder.match('(?<=\"\>)\w*')
      ^
```

I'm guessing the reason is the quotes interfering.

Comment: Those three lines don't cause any problems for me, when pasted into a ruby block in irb. I suspect your problem is upstream.

Answer (score 2):

Your "unexpected tIDENTIFIER" error is coming from somewhere else, you should be getting an

```
undefined method `match' for #<Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet:...>
```

error since [`xpath`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable.html#xpath-instance_method) gives you a [`Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html) and those don't have `match` methods.

Your XPath expression appears to uniquely identify the single `<a>` you're after so you should just use [`at`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#at-instance_method) to get the node and then [`text`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#text-instance_method) to extract the content:

```
text = $page_html.at(...).text
```

Then you can simply [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split) off the first word:

```
user = text.split.first
```

Also, you'll want to be careful with that XPath:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/a
```

That looks like it came from a browser and some browsers will insert `<tbody>` elements into `<table>`s but Nokogiri won't. You might need to adjust the XPath to match the real structure of the HTML you're scraping.

Answer (score 1):

You must be missing a closing bracket somewhere earlier in your source. That is what it means when it says you're missing the keyword end.

```
2.0.0p0 :004 > $holder = '<a href="http://www.foo.bar">example_text (a)</a>'
 => "<a href=\"http://www.foo.bar\">example_text (a)</a>" 
2.0.0p0 :005 > $user = $holder.match('(?<=\"\>)\w*')
 => #<MatchData "example_text">
```